# How to use `DT::renderDT()` with both `option` argument and `formatCurrency()`

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a table displayed within a Shiny application using `DT::renderDT()` like so:

```
DT::renderDT(tab %>% 
            selection = "none",
            extensions = 'Buttons',
            option = list(buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
                          dom = 'Brti')
          )
```

and then I wanted to use the `formatCurrency()` function as well:

```
DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(tab) %>% 
              DT::formatCurrency(columns = 2:5, 
                                 currency = '',                                 
                                 mark = " ",
                                 digits = 0),
            selection = "none", 
            extensions = 'Buttons',
            option = list(buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
                          dom = 'Brti')
          )
```

and get the following warning:
`Warning in processWidget(instance) : renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable`
i.e. I can't provide both the `datatable()` object itself and the `renderDT()` with options.

Unfortunately I didn't find the way of using the `formatCurrency()` function directly within the `DT::renderDT()` function, can anyone tell me how I should do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the arguments need to be passed in the `datatable` call:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(datasets)

tab <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(DT::DTOutput("myTable"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myTable <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      tab,
      selection = "none",
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      option = list(
        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
        dom = 'Brti'
      )
    ) %>%
      DT::formatCurrency(
        columns = 2:5,
        currency = '',
        mark = " ",
        digits = 0
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I understood from some readings that some options are only available within `DT::renderDT()` and not `DT::datatable()`, but maybe this is not true? i.e. are all options available for `DT::renderDT()` can be given directly to `DT::datatable()`?

Comment: Please see `?renderDT` arguments "...": `ignored when expr returns a table widget, and passed as additional arguments to datatable() when expr returns a data object`. -  Accordingly `renderDT` just passes the arguments to `datatable` in case you supply data and not a `datatable` object (just a convenience feature of `renderDT`).