# Shiny data table populated by user input on radio buttons

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I'm new to Shiny, and trying to create a app in which the the main panel is a tabpanel. The first tab is a conditional panel (these are dictated by the 'criteria' sidepanel selection), and the second tab should be a table representing the highest user-selected radio button options from the conditional panel for each question (e.g., if they select 'Option 1' for 'Question 1' (conditional panel 1) and 'Option 2' for 'Question 2 (conditional panel , Option 2), this should display Question 1 - 2. This information needs to be retained as the user moves through the different criteria on the sidepannel. The issues I'm having are 1. I'm not sure how to retain values based on radio button selection, and 2. I'm not sure how to generate a table that will update to reflect the user input as they work through the criteria.
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                
                # Application title
                titlePanel("TITLE"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("select", label =  helpText("Select a critera"), 
                        choices = list("Criteria_1", "Criteria_2"), 
                        selected = c("NULL"))),
                        
                    
                    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Criteria", conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
                            condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
                            prettyRadioButtons(
                                inputId = "Id037",
                                label = "Predictions:", 
                                choices = c(
                                "Option 1" = 1, 
                                "Option 2" = 2,
                                "Option 3" = 3),
                                inline = TRUE, 
                                status = "danger",
                                fill = TRUE),
                               
                        ),
                        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
                            condition =  "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
                            prettyRadioButtons(
                                inputId = "Id037",
                                label = "Hypotheses:", 
                                choices = c(
                                    "Option 1" = 1, 
                                    "Option 2" = 2, 
                                    "Option 3" = 3),
                                inline = TRUE, 
                                status = "danger",
                                fill = TRUE)
                        ),
                     
                                          
#User side-pannel selection - criteria 2               
                        
                        
conditionalPanel( h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
                  condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_2'",
                  prettyRadioButtons(
                      inputId = "Id037",
                      label = "Methods:", 
                      choices = c(
                          "Option 1" = 1, 
                          "Option 2" = 2),
                      inline = TRUE, 
                      status = "danger",
                      fill = TRUE)
                  
),
conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
    condition =  "input.stats == 'Criteria 2'",
    prettyRadioButtons(
        inputId = "Id037",
        label = "Paradigm:", 
        choices = c(
            "Option 1" = 1, 
            "Option 2" = 2, 
            "Option 3" = 3),
        inline = TRUE, 
        status = "danger",
        fill = TRUE)
)),
  
                        
                         tabPanel("Summary score", DT::renderDT({
                           datatable() %>% formatStyle(
                             'Sepal.Width',
                             backgroundColor = styleInterval(3.4, c('gray', 'yellow'))
                           )
                         })),
                        
                        ))
                ))

                server <- function(input, output) {
                    
                }
                
                shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have the same `inputId` for all your radiobuttons. Would make each of them unique (perhaps call them "Id037", "Id038", etc.). Then, the radiobutton values can change and be retained. As for your `renderDT` - would replace with `DTOutput` and move the `renderDT` to the server function. You can see plenty of examples using this such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63599286/3460670). You can refer to and access the radiobutton data via `input$Id037` or whatever your `inputId` will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ben pointed out. each `radioButtons()` must have a unique inputId. Also, `renderDT` should go inside the server part. In the ui we need `DToutput`.

Regarding question two of criteria_2, the conditions mentions input.stats but there's no input called stats so i changed it to select.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                
                # Application title
                titlePanel("TITLE"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("select", label =  helpText("Select a critera"), 
                                    choices = list("Criteria_1", "Criteria_2"), 
                                    selected = c("NULL"))),
                    
                    
                    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Criteria", conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
                                                              condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
                                                              prettyRadioButtons(
                                                                  inputId = "Id037",
                                                                  label = "Predictions:", 
                                                                  choices = c(
                                                                      "Option 1" = 1, 
                                                                      "Option 2" = 2,
                                                                      "Option 3" = 3),
                                                                  inline = TRUE, 
                                                                  status = "danger",
                                                                  fill = TRUE),
                                                              
                        ),
                        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
                                         condition =  "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
                                         prettyRadioButtons(
                                             inputId = "Id038",
                                             label = "Hypotheses:", 
                                             choices = c(
                                                 "Option 1" = 1, 
                                                 "Option 2" = 2, 
                                                 "Option 3" = 3),
                                             inline = TRUE, 
                                             status = "danger",
                                             fill = TRUE)
                        ),
                        
                        
                        #User side-pannel selection - criteria 2               
                        
                        
                        conditionalPanel( h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
                                          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_2'",
                                          prettyRadioButtons(
                                              inputId = "Id039",
                                              label = "Methods:", 
                                              choices = c(
                                                  "Option 1" = 1, 
                                                  "Option 2" = 2),
                                              inline = TRUE, 
                                              status = "danger",
                                              fill = TRUE)
                                          
                        ),
                        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
                                         condition =  "input.select == 'Criteria_2'",
                                         prettyRadioButtons(
                                             inputId = "Id040",
                                             label = "Paradigm:", 
                                             choices = c(
                                                 "Option 1" = 1, 
                                                 "Option 2" = 2, 
                                                 "Option 3" = 3),
                                             inline = TRUE, 
                                             status = "danger",
                                             fill = TRUE)
                        )),
                        

# Second Tab --------------------------------------------------------------

                        
                        tabPanel("Summary score",
                                 DTOutput('summary')),
                        
                    ))
                )
)

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    
    summ <- reactive({
        
       radios_inputid <- str_c('Id0', seq(37, 40, 1))        
       radios_values <- map(radios_inputid, ~input[[.x]])
                   
        
       tibble(Criteria = c('Criteria_1','Criteria_1','Criteria_2', 'Criteria_2'),
              Input_name = radios_inputid,
              value = radios_values) 
    })
    
    
   output$summary <-  DT::renderDT({
        datatable(summ())
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit:

To obtain the minimum value of each criteria:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("united"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("TITLE"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select",
        label = helpText("Select a critera"),
        choices = list("Criteria_1", "Criteria_2"),
        selected = c("NULL")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Criteria", conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id037_crit1",
            label = "Predictions:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          ),
        ),
        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id038_crit1",
            label = "Hypotheses:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          )
        ),


        # User side-pannel selection - criteria 2


        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_2'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id039_crit2",
            label = "Methods:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          )
        ),
        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_2'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id040_crit2",
            label = "Paradigm:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          )
        )
      ),


      # Second Tab --------------------------------------------------------------


      tabPanel(
        "Summary score",
        DTOutput("summary")
      ),
    ))
  )
)

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
    
  calc_min_val <- function(contains) {
    radios_inputid <- str_subset(names(input), contains)
    map_dbl(radios_inputid, ~ as.numeric(input[[.x]])) %>%
        min()
  }


  summ <- reactive({
    min_values <- c("crit1$", "crit2$") %>%
        map(calc_min_val)



    tibble(
      Lowest_Criteria = c("Criteria_1", "Criteria_2"),
      value = map(min_values, ~.)
    )
  })


  output$summary <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(summ())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It works fantastically, I'm really grateful for your time. Just a quick question, is there a simple way to change the table to only show only the lowest value for Criteria 1 & 2? That is, if Criteria 2 Q1 response is option 1, and Q2 response is option 3, is there a simple way to show only one vaule for criteria 2 corresponding to the lowest score (in this case, 1)?

Comment: @Jen I edited my answer for getting the min value of each criteria, notice that I added in the inputId's crit1 or crit2 to then be able to know which values to pair. Basically all the `map` functions are retrieving the input values and calculating the min.

Comment: thanks a million. That's really so helpful!